# ghostscript generates header in resulting pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a pdf with form fields on it. I want to "flatten" this into a pdf without form fields but when i run the original pdf through ghostscript, the resulting pdf file has a banner at the top that says: "In order to submit this form, you should open it with Adobe Acrobat Reader"

[image]

If I tell ghostscript not to render the form fields the banner does not appear, but neither do the form fields.

Is there any way to print the pdf with the form fields using ghostscript without generating this banner.

Running on FBSD,  Ghostscript v9.22

The command line is :

gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "-sOutputFile=/tmp/flatened.pdf" -dBATCH "/tmp/Sample PDF w fillable fields.pdf"

[A sample PDF file:](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TexasNeo/uploads/main/Sample%20PDF%20w%20fillable%20fields.pdf)

[A sample results file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TexasNeo/uploads/main/flatened.pdf)

Comment: I uploaded a sample PDF, and the sample results. When I viewed the sample pdf in firefox, the browsers viewer gave me the same banner, but upon downloading it and view it Acrobat, the banner was gone. The results file has it in there regardless.

Comment: This may be related to how the pdf was generated (I was handed this as an example). It was generated via jotform and god knows what they are doing.

Comment: Yea, i was able to get a hold of a copy of the full acrobat and create a fallible form pdf, then i filled it on another computer and sent the filled pdf through GS and it worked without issue. This is related to jotform.

Comment: I have taken your information back to management with a recommendation we do not support this configuration, i believe this may have been handed to me as a simple test case and not one that is representative of the actual use cases we will encounter.

Answer (score 0):

This seams to be related to how the PDF for generated, it was generated via jotform, and this is a known issue at jotform. Form generated via adobe acrobat work fine.